# [Android - Solution]Click two button in a same time in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem in Android code. I have two button in an fragment:

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(...);
Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(...);
```

buttonOne will show a dialog and buttonTwo will change my fragment. When i click both buttonOne and buttonTwo in a same time (buttonOne clicked before buttonTwo in a few second), a dialog showed but the fragment had changed (because after buttonOne is clicked, when the dialog's not showed yet, buttonTwo is clicked next and change the fragment) Now, when i click a button in the dialog and change something, my app crashed.

It's not a normal case but i wonder how i can prevent buttonTwo is clicked when buttonOne was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a timer which will act as a threshold before you can click another button again.

**example:**

```
       @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Preventing multiple clicks, using threshold of 1 second
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 500) {
        return;
          }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    ///YOUR BUTTON CLICK HERE
}
```

So it will have a threshold of 500 millisecond before you can click another button

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But Does have another way to handle this event?