# Launch App on clicking power and volume up button in Android

Tags: android

I want to launch my app on pressing power and volume up button together. 
I am able to launch the app on volumeChange but the default increase/decrease of volume functionality is overrided. 
So, Can anyone let me know how to do with the combination of two buttons?

I am launching the app this way, which works fine.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Need help to handle on pressing keys event.

Thanks,
Adheesh.

Comment: what about writing on [this magic site](http://www.google.com) something like "intercept power button android" and "intercept volume up button android"?

Comment: I found few solutions for intercepting the single button press, But I wanted to do it on pressing the buttons together. Thats where I am having an issue..

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23959886/4700782)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect two hardware button press simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420414/detect-two-hardware-button-press-simultaneously)

Comment: @pier - I can't implement that because the app won't be in running state to do that and that is the code for button press.  I am looking for handling key press events.

Comment: @Klein - Looked into the link and found two ways of doing this, but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this code to listen for the volume button before.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        //Do something
    }
    return true;
}
```